# how to see if associative array key is equal to zero?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array in PHP:

```
$num = array(0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>0);
```

I need to show the number in the key if the value is zero.

In this example, the result would be only number 3.

Comment: that is an _Indexed array_, not _Associative array_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $num = array(0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>0);

    foreach($num as $k => $v) {

        if($v == 0)
            echo $k;

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) in this case:

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

```
$num = array(0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>0);
$key = array_search(0, $num);
echo $key;
```

FYI: that ain't an associative array.

If you want to get multiple occurances of zeroes, use `array_keys()` instead:

```
$num = array(0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>0, 4=>0);
$key = array_keys($num, 0);
print_r($key); // Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 )
```

Comment: @Rizier123 this returns the key of the found needle you provided, if not found it will return `false`. if you want multiple occurances of keys, you could use `array_keys()` with the second parameter usage

Comment: I mean if you use this array: `$num = array(0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>0, 4 => 0);` Is there a way with your solution to display 3 and 4 ?

Comment: @Rizier123 you would need to use another function, very useful also, check my revision above. of course if that would be the case, in the OP's current question above, array search is sufficient

Comment: +1 for a good and explained answer! Also very fast and friendly feedback to comments :D

Comment: nice answer just now hearing about these functions this community helps me a lot in programming :-)

Comment: accordingly to w3schools - Associative arrays are arrays that use named keys that you assign to them.

anyway, this code only give me the first key where value is zero, and i need all of them. 
anyway i got my answer, but thank you so much for your time. Even if i allready got the answer, you were very helpful

Comment: @DiogoAlexandreCavalheiro no prob, just pick the answer thats best fit for you :)

Comment: @Rizier123 well, no reason to be impolite :) we are here to learn more things on our field anyways.