# Print items of array if it has values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [jeans] => Array
        (
            [blue] => 3
            [pink] => 1
            [red] => 0
        )

    [shirts] => Array
        (
            [blue] => 5
            [pink] => 0
            [red] => 0
        )
    [pijama] => Array
        (
            [blue] => 0
            [pink] => 0
            [red] => 0
        )
)
```

How can I print if jeans or shirts have items of color?
For example:
"Jeans has 3 blue items."
"Jeans has 1 pink item."
"shirts has 5 red items."
I'm not interested in obtain the ones with 0. I was thinking in a foreach, but I don't know how to.

Comment: If you are going to write PHP you had better spend a little time getting familiar with foreach

Comment: So you actually want to output the text `Jeans has three blue items.` and not `Jeans has 3 blue items.`

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, with number "Jeans has 3 blue items"

Comment: `$array['jeans']['blue']` will be the number of blue jeans.

Comment: It sounds like you just wan nested loops. `foreach ($array as $item => $colors) { foreach ($colors as $color => $quantity) ...`

Comment: Inverse logic [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878976/2943403); [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39202491/2943403) looks topical

Answer (score 2):

A couple of foreach loops will do this for you

```
$clothes = [
                'jeans' => ['blue' => 3, 'pink' => 1, 'red' => 0],
                'shirts' => ['blue' => 5, 'pink' => 0, 'red' => 0],
                'pijama' => ['blue' => 0, 'pink' => 0, 'red' => 0],
];

foreach( $clothes as $item => $colours ){
    foreach( $colours as $colour => $num ) {
        if ( $num > 0 ){
            printf("%s has %d %s items\n", $item, $num, $colour);
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
jeans has 3 blue items
jeans has 1 blue items
shirts has 5 blue items
```